# Contents of reports getting overwritten . Need to refresh parent page?

Tags: javascript, html, session-variables, struts-1

Please find the summary of my query:-

Lets say I start off at my homepage :- https://example.com//homepage

At the homepage I have links to certain documents .Once I click on one of the links it takes me to a page where I am asked to fill information and I can finally submit it.

I fill the information ,click on submit it takes me to final signature page where it asks me to enter my credentials so that it can post a timestamp saying that I have authored this document at this particular time.

Now I close this window and return to the homepage and click on another document link ,**WITHOUT REFRESHING THE HOMEPAGE** and follow the same steps. For some some odd reason when I complete this document I see that details mentioned in the first report have been leaked\merged\overwritten into this document.BIZZARE!!

So I did a bit of research(soul searching if you may say) and I found the reason could be because the session is still having the old data from the old document ?Basically what I tried was when I manually refreshed the homepage ,this issue didn't occur. So what I am trying to do now is ,every time I SIGN off the document, i.e reach the final signature page and click no 'SUBMIT' button , I want the homepage ,viz https://example.com/homepage to refresh.

Below is the snippet of JSCRIPT that is being called when I click on 'SUBMIT' button on the signature page:-(this is basically the onclick function for that 'SUBMIT' HTML function )

```
function completeForm(aForm)
   {  
      var foundError = false;

      if(validateRequiredInput(aForm.loginID)  &
         validateRequiredInput(aForm.password) )
      {         
           document.getElementById("submitBtn").disabled = true;
      // Modified to get the newWindow request Parameter by Nidhi Prakash Srivastava for clinSIGHT release 2.0.6
      var newWindow = "";
      if(aForm.getNewWindow != null)
      {
        newWindow=aForm.getNewWindow.value;
      }
      // Modified to get the newEPCWindow request Parameter by Nidhi Prakash Srivastava for clinSIGHT release 2.0.10      
      var newEPCWindow = "";
      var newQCWindow = "";

      if(aForm.getNewEPCWindow != null && aForm.action.indexOf("?") < 0)
      {

        newEPCWindow=aForm.getNewEPCWindow.value;

        aForm.action = aForm.action+"?op=complete&newWindow="+newWindow+"&newEPCWindow="+newEPCWindow;
      }else if(aForm.getNewQCWindow != null && aForm.action.indexOf("?") < 0){
        newQCWindow=aForm.getNewQCWindow.value;
        aForm.action = aForm.action+"?op=complete&newWindow="+newWindow+"&newQCWindow="+newQCWindow;
      }else if(aForm.action.indexOf("?") < 0)
      {
        aForm.action = aForm.action+"?op=complete&newWindow="+newWindow;
      }

         onsubmitFormHandler();
         aForm.submit();
      }
```

How do I go about achieveing the refresh of the homepage from here? Is this even the right approach ? Any suggestions on the same ?

Comment: I don't quite follow the issue, but it sounds like the session is being managed incorrectly, and data that should be overwritten is only being appended. Impossible to say. But if it's a session form, sounds like it needs to be reset.

Comment: @DaveNewton I understand the issue might be a bit complex... bu as for the solution.. I am farely confident the refreshing of the JSP's will help out. Any idea as to how I can achieve the refresh as mentioned in the problem summary ?

Comment: Is it a session or request form? Reloading a page is pretty easy, but won't solve the problem if it's a session form that doesn't get reset.

Comment: @DaveNewton it's a request form. The trick here is I need to get the page that opens up at the very begining(mentioned the specifics in my problem summary ) to be refreshed from the 3rd child when I click on the submit button.